# Using Multiple Input Devices in Python Audio Processing (Pyo)

Tags: python, audio, pyo

**TLDR: Is there a way to mix multiple input devices' audio streams in real-time in Python (ideally with Pyo)?**

I'm trying to use [Pyo](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/index.html) to combine audio streams from multiple microphones (or virtual microphones, e.g., Loopback devices) into one output audio stream. I've tried using `pyo.Input`, but it seems to have a core limitation: in `Input(x)`, `x` seems to refer to a channel, not an input device. The input device seems to be constrained by the server: for `s = pyo.Server(duplex=1)`, `s.setInputDevice(someDeviceIndex)` seems to be the only way to choose which input device will be used, with `x` then referring to a channel of that device (e.g., for a stereo microphone).

I have not seen any information in Pyo's docs (or in what I've read about other libraries) about how to mix multiple input devices together. `pyo.Mixer` seems promising, but examples given in the docs don't demonstrate how to use multiple `Input`s, just other sound sources (e.g., a sine wave).

Is there any way that I can access multiple input devices within the scope of one `Server` and mix them together? If Pyo is not a good option for this task, what other libraries (and/or vanilla Python) might be a good fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved on the Pyo forums at [this link](https://groups.google.com/g/pyo-discuss/c/8QQim3dE1-U/m/a7QuOrbEAAAJ).